# Rails: Opposite of Hash#to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I convert a hash to a query string, how can I convert it back again?

```
{:filters => {:colour => ['Red', 'Blue'], :size => 'Medium'}}.to_param
=> "filters[colour][]=Red&filters[colour][]=Blue&filters[size]=Medium"
```

Rails appears to do this automatically when it populates the `params` hash, but is it possible to call this method directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're looking for `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query)`, which will convert it back into a `Hash`. You can get it by using this line:

```
require 'rack/utils'
```

Comment: `Rack::Utils.build_nested_query('filters[colour][]=Red&filters[colour][]=Blue&filters[size]=Medium')` results in `ArgumentError: value must be a Hash`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ahh, I see you've edited your answer. `parse_nested_query` works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @gjb: yeah sorry my bad, I get the two confused all the time.

Comment: Nil values are not preserved, they will be empty strings instead:
`Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query({foo: nil}.to_param) => {"foo"=>""}`

Answer (score 1):

```
query_string = "filters[colour][]=Red&filters[colour][]=Blue&filters[size]=Medium"
CGI::parse(query_string)
```

Comment: Good, but not quite there. This does not generate a hash with a filters key which has a hash with a colour key which has an *array* as a value... which is what `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` does.